# Q-Value Less than P-Value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, false-discovery-rate

I have a list of p-values from a series of regression equations. Many of these P-values are small. To compute false discovery rate I have been using the q-value package in R. I notice, based on this analysis, that P-values of 0.05 correspond to q-values that are smaller than the p values (0.03).  Would I then say that my false discovery rate is smaller than my P value? Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, if the proportion of null hypotheses (which is estimated by the qvalue package based on your p-value distribution) is small *and* your test is powerful.

Here's an example. Let's say you're testing 1000 hypotheses, and let's say 200 (20%) are actually null- this proportion is called $\pi_0$. Assume the qvalue package accurately estimates this value (see [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/100/16/9440.full) for more on how it does that, and note that you can see what it estimates for your data with `qvalue(mypvalues)$pi0`). Furthermore, let's say that 500 of your p-values are under .05 (your test is powerful). Then what would be the q-value corresponding to a p-value of .05?

The q-value is the expected proportion of false discoveries you would obtain by setting a particular p-value cutoff. In your 200 null hypotheses, the p-values are uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 (that's part of the definition of a p-value). This means that 5% of them (10 hypotheses) will fall under .05. So you have 500 hypotheses under .05, and you expect 10 of them to be false: your expected FDR is $10/500=.02%$. In this case, the q-value is indeed smaller than the p-value.

Comment: I have two datasets, one with the issue above (pvals > qvals) and a dataset that followed the expected (pvals < qvals). Following your post, however, i noticed that the latter dataset has a π0 of 1.0. Can I then trust the hypotheses that fall below a certain FDR (0.05)?

Comment: @AlanGarciaElfring generally yes! Most methods to estimate  $\pi_0$ are conservative (they intentionally prefer an overestimate to an underestimate), which means it could be estimated at 1 even if there are true positives. When $\pi_0$ is 1, then the q-value method becomes equivalent to Benjamini-Hochberg FDR control.

Answer (score 3):

You do not *compute* the false discovery rate, you *control* the false discovery rate.

Family-wise error rate methods (e.g. Bonferroni, Holm-Sidák, etc.) attempt to control the probability of making a false rejection of H$_{0}$ while assuming that *all* null hypotheses are true.

False discovery rate methods attempt to control the probability of of making a false rejection of H$_{0}$ while assuming that *some* null hypotheses are false. In this context $q$-values, are $p$-values that have been adjusted using a method to control the false discovery rate. $q$-values should be greater than or equal to the $p$-values from which they are computed, but it is difficult to say more about why you are getting the results you are without seeing your code.